# Canceling Job doesn't stop suspend functions inside its scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a request in backend server, where I am search in parallel for products from different inventories.
If one of the calls was unsuccessful, this server call must **immediately** stop all other requests and return error to the user/client, with some http error (500)

I noticed it works only when I use a dummy "delay" function, but when I use the actual code that fetches data from inventory, they are all still waiting for completion instead of aborting immediately.

I understand that the `delay` function uses `suspendCancellableCoroutine` and is `cancellable`, but I don't understand how to turn the inventory call to be cancellable in the same way.

```
 override suspend fun searchPackages(req: RequestFromClient): PackageResult? {

     var products1: List<Product1>
     var products2: List<Product2>

     val job = Job()

     val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job).launch {

         val req1 = async {
             products1 = products(req.type1) // will use inventory X
             if (products1 == null)
                 job.cancel() // --> this should stop all other async tasks immediately
         }

         val req2 = async {
             products2 = products(req.type2) // will use inventory Y
             if (products2 == null)
                job.cancel() // --> this should stop all other async tasks immediately
         }

         listOf(req1, req2).awaitAll()
     }
     scope.join()

     if (req1 == null || req2 == null) return null
       
} 

suspend fun products(req: Request) {
     try {

         inventory.searchProducts(req) // -> doesn't work (continues to wait for completion)

//       delay(timeMillis = timeMillis(seconds = 20)) // -> works good (stops immediately)

     } catch (e: CancellationException) {
         println("CancellationException") // --> called only for the 'delay' function
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the `inventory.searchProducts()` function?

Comment: I just looked at the inner implementation of inventory, turns out it's an API we have that is built in Java. So that's probably the issue. 
When I switched to an http client of kotlin (Ktor) , it suddenly worked (ALTHOUGH - the CancellationException was called internally somewhere judgin by the logs, and not in the `Catch` I wrote)

Comment: Is there a way around this, if the inventory calls a java based client?

Comment: If the Java code provides a way to both start and *cancel* it, you can build a proper cancellable suspend function version of the call by using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. The typical thing to do is to create an extension function that acts as a synchronous suspend function overload of the  asynchronous Java function. If the Java code does not provide a way to cancel requests, you're out of luck in both Kotlin or Java.

Comment: Thank you. I wrapped the java api call with `suspendCancellableCoroutine ` and it seems to work.  Although I do see an internal exception when that happens, but it does get aborted and my code in the post can proceed to return response to client. I'm wondering is it a good practice to do it though? Is there anything I should consider before implementing this solution?

Comment: After I wrapped the java api call with `suspendCancellateCoroutine` I see internally in the terminal : `java.lang.InterruptedException: null
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:386) ~[?:?]`. And the code seems to behave as I intended

Comment: Might be perfectly fine and expected depending on how your backend works and how you implemented your suspend function.

Comment: If it's a blocking API, wrap it with [`runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO) {`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html).

Comment: @GeorgeLeung but the runInterruptible is called from a scope `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)`, so it's already Dispatchers.IO. why would it matter then?

Comment: Then you don't have to provide `Dispatchers.IO` to `runInterruptible`. The point is `runInterruptible` converts the coroutine cancellation to a thread interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling a coroutine is cooperative. If the code being cancelled don't want to be cancelled, then it can't be stopped. The code might also just be ignorant of the cancellation request, as it will be with java code that wasn't intended to work with kotlin coroutines.

Using `delay` (or just `yield`) checks if there is a cancellation request and will honor it by stopping the current coroutine. And Ktor uses coroutines internally, that's why you don't experience any problems there.

As to your actual java code, it must be made aware of the cancellation request. As @Tenfour04 already suggested in their comment, it could be as simple as wrapping it in a couroutine that checks for a cancellation request and calls the appropriate cancel method of your java code.